# How are variables uv initialized?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, documentation

I am reading through the documentation for FEM programming, in particular the section for transient coupled PDEs, [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html#1433571051). I do not understand how the variable `uv` is initialized: this should be a vector containing the dependent variables, but I do not see the initialization and in the final step, while solving the time differential equations they are solved for in `NDSolveValue`, but they seem to be a scalar from the code. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. `uv` is initialized with `uv[0] == init, uv'[0] == dinit` in that NDSolve call. Note that in this case NDSolve is used purely as a time integrator the spatial discretization was done manually. The dependent variables `u` and `v` are one long list of values something like `uv=Join[u,v]`. Does that help?

Comment: @user21 But where in the code was this `uv=Join[u,v]` done? Following the code I do not see a line of code in which this identification was done. This is why I think `uv` in the `NDSolve` call is a scalar

Comment: There is a section `dof = methodData["DegreesOfFreedom"]; init = dinit = ConstantArray[0, {dof, 1}];` And then `uv[0] == init, uv'[0] == dinit` in the call to `NDSolve`. With this you specify the initial conditions and the derivative of the initial conditions at each node as vector.

Comment: Note that, for example, the stiffness matrix is for `u` and `v` 233 DOF for u and 233 for v. Together this is 466 DOF. That is why later you have the `split` to separate them for an interpolation function for each u and v. When you do `vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables", 
     "Space"} -> {{u, v}, {x, y}}];` you create a coupled system of PDE. Does that help?

Comment: @user21 yes now I understand, thanks!

Comment: Can you do me a favor: I'd like to improve the documentation for this. If you could write me a very small paragraph of of what would have helped you I can include this in the documentation and hopefully make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a section

```
dof = methodData["DegreesOfFreedom"];
init = dinit = ConstantArray[0, {dof, 1}];
```

And then

```
uv[0] == init
uv'[0] == dinit
```

in the call to NDSolve. With this you specify the initial conditions and the derivative of the initial conditions at each node as vector.

The stiffness matrix is for `u` and `v`. 233 DOF for `u` and 233 for `v`. Together this is 466 DOF. That is why later you have the split to separate them for an interpolation function for each `u` and `v`. When you do

```
vd = NDSolveVariableData[{"DependentVariables", "Space"} -> {{u, v}, {x,y}}];
```

you create a coupled system of PDE.